# Redis ACL architecture

Tags: database-design, architecture, redis

I would like to use redis to check if users have permissions for certain places on a website.

The website allows users to create groups with limited features. There are essentially two types of users (potentially more) - Admins and Readers. One user can partake in different groups (10-15 groups)

**First idea** - create redis hashes for each user and include the groups that they are Admins for and the groups they are Readers. I can then control these by removing the records upon log out and setting the permissions upon login and change. Also the hash can expire.

**Second idea** - create hashes for each group and store the members that are admins and the members that are readers. This has the benefit that there will probably be less groups than members and I can pull the group's details too.

So my two questions are -

**Which approach is better in terms of architecture?**

**Should I even be using Hashes (since I'll end up with something like `group:1 admins [13,52,12,43]` where the array holds the users ids or should I use something else where I can quickly pull the `user id` without having to parse the array and then loop through it every time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a slightly different approach, that IMO suits the use case better.

I assume that each of your users has a unique identifier. Lets agree that you're using plain old numbers (or that you have a lookup table that map a user id to a plain old number). From now on, users will be known as 0 (the first user), 1 (the 2nd users) and so forth...

I also assume that the total number of users far exceeds the number of potential groups you'll have in the system. Put differently, you'll millions of users but only tens of groups (more or less).

It appears that what you want is, given a user (number) find what groups (finite, smallish set) she/he belongs to.

Have you heard of [BITMAP](https://redis.io/commands/bitmap)s? You can have a Bitmap in which the bits' indices represent user ids, 0 means that the user isn't in the group and 1 means belongingness. LMK if you need more details or mark this as the answer if it makes sense.

Comment: I haven't heard of BITMAPs before. I'm new to Redis. I'm reading about it now. Quick question - what if I have multiple roles for that group and not just two?

Comment: Finish reading, think about it, and open a new question if needed... ;)

Comment: Happy for you - now, go and make something awesome ;p

Comment: Itamar, I just wanted to, again, say thank you for the answer. I'll build my ACL around this concept. It's v helpful.